# Can I use Office 2007 and 2010 together?

Tags: office-2007, office-2010

I have a new laptop with Office 2010 Starter on it. That means it contains only Microsoft Word and Excel, but I need PowerPoint, too. Since I have Office 2007, I thought to install only PowerPoint on that laptop, but I'm not sure if that works. Any ideas?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, both programs store in different installed folders and registry, for example: `Office12` for Office 2007 product; `Office14` for Office 2010 product. So, I assume they can be installed side-by-side. Except if they are on different architecture: 32-bit or 64-bit; so, they cannot be mixed in that case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can install 2010 along side 2007, and run either one of them. You just need to make sure that you install 2010 in a different directory than 2007. Outlook 2010 will replace Outlook 2007 automatically though, if you installed it (I know you don't plan to, but I am just pointing that out.)

Though, as ee pointed out, if your laptop is 64 bit and the office 2007 that you have is 32 bit, or vice versa, you will not be able to install that version of 2007 on the laptop.